# Using fade in animation for a view

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to have a `View` that initially is invisible and when I press a button, it becomes visible with a fade in animation. I'm using the `AlphaAnimation` for the fading effect. The problem is that if I make the view invisible the animation can't be seen.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Provide an `AnimationListener` to the Animation and make the View visible as soon as the Animation starts.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! The problem is that the application is not performed if the view is invisible, so the onStartAnimation method couldn't be used. But Ive set the view visible in the button's listener, before starting the animation, and I'm setting the view to be invisible in the onEndAnimation.

Comment: I don't understand why you set the animation to invisible in onEndAnimation, in your initial question you say that you want it to fade in and become visible, why you set to invisible in onEndAnimation?

Answer (score 126):

Suppose you have an `ImageView` named `imageView` and an animation file `your_fade_in_anim.xml` inside your res\anim\ folder:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.your_fade_in_anim);
// Now Set your animation
imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
```

**Your XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha 
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:duration="[duration (in milliseconds)]"
        android:repeatCount="infinite" />
</set>
```

Replace the brackets with your actual duration.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of the view being initially invisible?

Comment: Why has this answer got so many upvotes? it doesn't even answer the question.

Comment: While it doesn't answer the question in the body, it answers the question of "How do I fade in a view", which is the title of the question. Because of that, I imagine a lot of people find this answer while looking for how to do animations (as I did). While not strictly the answer, it is definitely useful.

Comment: Simple use `fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);`

Comment: to lxx it solves the problem as the alpha value 0.0 that it starts at is invisible.

Comment: android:fillAfter="true" adding this attribute to the xml will complete this animation

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the infinite repeat count and hiding/viewing your View, I suggest to just not repeat the animation and initially start with the alpha channel set to maximum. Then you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha 
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:duration="[duration (in milliseconds)]"
        android:repeatCount="0" />
</set>
```

And you're done. No need for a Listener, hiding or showing. Just as simple.