# android make a view display slowly

Tags: android, user-interface, opacity, transparent

I would like to make an UI effect when a View becomes slowly visible on the screen.

```
     <View
            android:id="@+id/header_vertical_divider_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/engraved_bg" />
```

where the drawable "engraved_bg" is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#880096ff"
      android:endColor="#88001d5e"
      android:angle="180" />
</shape>
```

How can I reach the effect where the drawable is invisible and the transparency is decreasing up to the current colours?

thanks in advance!

Comment: In Android everything is slow...

Answer (score 0):

You need an animation for this - check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090285/using-fade-in-animation-for-a-view) and just fiddle with the duration parameter.