# How to make text appear after clicking a button

Tags: java, android

I want to appear a text (or button, whatever) after a button is clicked:

```
button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
```

- Now what? Create an intent?

Let's say there's a textView that I want to have shown after the button5 is clicked. How-to?

Comment: in on click `textView.setText("text on click of button")`  have the textview in xml initialize in onCreate and set the text on button click. IF you want the text to be shown only after button click set the `visibility` to `invisible` in xml and on click of button 5 change it to `visible`

Comment: If you don't want the `TextView` to be shown at all until the `Button` is clicked, then toggle the `visibility`. Have it set to `invisible` in your xml then `textViewName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`. Otherwise, do what @Raghunandan said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's say there's a textView that I want to have shown after the button5 is clicked. How-to?

Define your `TextView` in XML as usual, but set its visibility to either `invisible` or `gone`:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          />
```

(`visibility="invisible"` means the `TextView` will take up space in the layout, as though it were there, but won't actually appear. `visibility="gone"` means the `TextView` will not take up space in the layout at all, as though it were not there.)

Then, in your `OnClickListener`:

```
textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

And the `TextView` will appear.

Alternatively, you can have the `TextView` be visible all along but with no text, and then call `setText()` in your listener.

Comment: As for how to make it fade in, see this answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5090470/348605

Comment: I understand the part to set the TextView invisible, but after that I get lost...

Answer (score 1):

You will just do whatever you need to do to your TextView inside your onClick event, an example of how this may look:

```
button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textViewInLayout);
                     //Change visibility                 
                     tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     //set a value in the textview
                     tv.setText("Hello World");
                }
    };
```

Comment: that is a different question.  I don't know for sure, but I assume you add a animation to the text view as a an attribute.  But that is a different question (and should be opened as a seperate SO entry)

Answer (score 0):

In your method onClick(View v) add a line:

```
myTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Where myTextView is the view containing the text you want to show.