# Creating fade in animation for images in listView

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

I am currently trying to set up my images in my list view so that when they are loaded, they are loaded with a fade in animation.

I have tried doing [this this method here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5090470/2657363) but my app crashes when I load the ListView with the error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: animator
"

If someone could give me some guidance on fading in my List View images, that would be great.

Class:

```
public class Fragment2 extends ListFragment {

public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context myContext;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        myContext = context;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.month);
        label.setText(month[position]);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.animator.animation);
        //Now Set your animation
        icon.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation );

        // Customize your icon here
        icon.setImageResource(drawables[position]);



        return row;
    }

}

int[] drawables = { R.drawable.transparent_picture, R.drawable.abstract_icon,
        R.drawable.animal_icon, R.drawable.anime_icon,
        R.drawable.artistic_icon, R.drawable.cartoon_icon,
        R.drawable.comic_icon, R.drawable.icon_celeberity,
        R.drawable.icon_cars, R.drawable.icon_fantasy,
        R.drawable.icon_food,

};

String[] month = { " ", "Abstract", "Animal", "Anime", "Artistic",
        "Cartoon", "Comics", "Celeberity", "Cars", "Fantasy", "Food" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.row, month);
    setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_layout2, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

Animation XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>

</animator>
```

Comment: Please show your animation setup code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `alpha` animation elements is not part of `animator`, is parts of `animation` element, to load `res` animator to android code you must use `Animator` class and for `res` animation you must make use of `Animation` class. for more information see [`Android Animation resources`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)