# Fade in while being initially invisible

Tags: android, animation, imageview

Following the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5090470/512998
I have successfully implemented fade in animation for my imageView. However, the imageView was initially visible and when the animation starts it just blink to become invisible(alpha=0.0) and slowly fade in back to alpha=1.0. Question here is, how do I set the imageView initially invisible?

I have tried to change the visibility in the xml layout to either `INVISIBLE` and `GONE` but the animation wont work. it will show as blank imageView in the final result.

I have also tried to change the alpha level of the imageView in xml layout, but turns out the animation is weird as it applies on top of the the alpha level that I configure. Example, if I set the alpha level to 0.3, the animation will fade between 0.0 to 0.3. If i set it to 0.0, it appears like no animation and image is not displayed at the end.

Here's the snippet of my codes:

**anim/fade_in_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha 
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:duration="1000"
        android:repeatCount="0" />
</set>
```

**layout/activity_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCharacter"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/darth_vader" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**src/MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCharacter);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SplashScreen.this, R.anim.fade_in_view);
            imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: check if loaded boolean is true or not??

Comment: ignore the loaded context as the variable is used to play a sound from the soundpool after being loaded

Comment: @pskink, thanks! it works by switching it to ObjectAnimator. only if you can post it as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your new Handler method

TO

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in_view);
                imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
                fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            }

        }, 1000);
```

and in activity_splash.xml

```
set imageview visibility to invisible
```